# SFGUI/C++ Compiling problems. Error 2019: unresolved external symbol

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2012, cmake, sfml, nmake

I'm trying to compile SFGUI library - it is GUI for SFML. I was following these instructions http://sfgui.sfml-dev.de/p/docs/guide/installing .

Firstly I've used CMake to generate makefile - I've set up generator as *NMake Makefiles*, then *Visual Studio 2012*. Then I've tried to compile it using NMake and Visual Studio 2013. Both generated the same errors shown below.

```
Error   1   error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol "__declspec(dllimport) public: class std::_String_const_iterator<class std::_String_val<struct std::_Simple_types<unsigned int> > > __thiscall sf::String::begin(void)const " (__imp_?begin@String@sf@@QBE?AV?$_String_const_iterator@V?$_String_val@U?$_Simple_types@I@std@@@std@@@std@@XZ) referenced in function "public: class sf::Vector2<float> __thiscall sfg::Engine::GetTextMetricsA(class sf::String const &,class sf::Font const &,unsigned int)const " (?GetTextMetricsA@Engine@sfg@@QBE?AV?$Vector2@M@sf@@ABVString@4@ABVFont@4@I@Z) C:\Program Files (x86)\CMake 2.8\bin\Engine.obj sfgui
Error   2   error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol "__declspec(dllimport) public: class std::_String_const_iterator<class std::_String_val<struct std::_Simple_types<unsigned int> > > __thiscall sf::String::begin(void)const " (__imp_?begin@String@sf@@QBE?AV?$_String_const_iterator@V?$_String_val@U?$_Simple_types@I@std@@@std@@@std@@XZ)  C:\Program Files (x86)\CMake 2.8\bin\Renderer.obj   sfgui
Error   3   error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol "__declspec(dllimport) public: class std::_String_const_iterator<class std::_String_val<struct std::_Simple_types<unsigned int> > > __thiscall sf::String::begin(void)const " (__imp_?begin@String@sf@@QBE?AV?$_String_const_iterator@V?$_String_val@U?$_Simple_types@I@std@@@std@@@std@@XZ)  C:\Program Files (x86)\CMake 2.8\bin\Window.cpp.obj sfgui
Error   4   error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol "__declspec(dllimport) public: class std::_String_const_iterator<class std::_String_val<struct std::_Simple_types<unsigned int> > > __thiscall sf::String::begin(void)const " (__imp_?begin@String@sf@@QBE?AV?$_String_const_iterator@V?$_String_val@U?$_Simple_types@I@std@@@std@@@std@@XZ)  C:\Program Files (x86)\CMake 2.8\bin\Entry.cpp.obj  sfgui
Error   5   error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol "__declspec(dllimport) public: class std::_String_const_iterator<class std::_String_val<struct std::_Simple_types<unsigned int> > > __thiscall sf::String::end(void)const " (__imp_?end@String@sf@@QBE?AV?$_String_const_iterator@V?$_String_val@U?$_Simple_types@I@std@@@std@@@std@@XZ) referenced in function "public: class sf::Vector2<float> __thiscall sfg::Engine::GetTextMetricsA(class sf::String const &,class sf::Font const &,unsigned int)const " (?GetTextMetricsA@Engine@sfg@@QBE?AV?$Vector2@M@sf@@ABVString@4@ABVFont@4@I@Z) C:\Program Files (x86)\CMake 2.8\bin\Engine.obj sfgui
Error   6   error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol "__declspec(dllimport) public: class std::_String_const_iterator<class std::_String_val<struct std::_Simple_types<unsigned int> > > __thiscall sf::String::end(void)const " (__imp_?end@String@sf@@QBE?AV?$_String_const_iterator@V?$_String_val@U?$_Simple_types@I@std@@@std@@@std@@XZ)  C:\Program Files (x86)\CMake 2.8\bin\Renderer.obj   sfgui
Error   7   error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol "__declspec(dllimport) public: class std::_String_const_iterator<class std::_String_val<struct std::_Simple_types<unsigned int> > > __thiscall sf::String::end(void)const " (__imp_?end@String@sf@@QBE?AV?$_String_const_iterator@V?$_String_val@U?$_Simple_types@I@std@@@std@@@std@@XZ)  C:\Program Files (x86)\CMake 2.8\bin\Window.cpp.obj sfgui
Error   8   error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol "__declspec(dllimport) public: class std::_String_const_iterator<class std::_String_val<struct std::_Simple_types<unsigned int> > > __thiscall sf::String::end(void)const " (__imp_?end@String@sf@@QBE?AV?$_String_const_iterator@V?$_String_val@U?$_Simple_types@I@std@@@std@@@std@@XZ)  C:\Program Files (x86)\CMake 2.8\bin\Entry.cpp.obj  sfgui
Error   9   error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol "__declspec(dllimport) public: class std::_String_iterator<class std::_String_val<struct std::_Simple_types<unsigned int> > > __thiscall sf::String::begin(void)" (__imp_?begin@String@sf@@QAE?AV?$_String_iterator@V?$_String_val@U?$_Simple_types@I@std@@@std@@@std@@XZ) referenced in function "private: unsigned int __thiscall sfg::Entry::GetPositionFromMouseX(int)" (?GetPositionFromMouseX@Entry@sfg@@AAEIH@Z)   C:\Program Files (x86)\CMake 2.8\bin\Entry.cpp.obj  sfgui
Error   10  error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol "__declspec(dllimport) public: class std::_String_iterator<class std::_String_val<struct std::_Simple_types<unsigned int> > > __thiscall sf::String::begin(void)" (__imp_?begin@String@sf@@QAE?AV?$_String_iterator@V?$_String_val@U?$_Simple_types@I@std@@@std@@@std@@XZ)    C:\Program Files (x86)\CMake 2.8\bin\Label.cpp.obj  sfgui
Error   11  error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol "__declspec(dllimport) public: class std::_String_iterator<class std::_String_val<struct std::_Simple_types<unsigned int> > > __thiscall sf::String::end(void)" (__imp_?end@String@sf@@QAE?AV?$_String_iterator@V?$_String_val@U?$_Simple_types@I@std@@@std@@@std@@XZ) referenced in function "private: unsigned int __thiscall sfg::Entry::GetPositionFromMouseX(int)" (?GetPositionFromMouseX@Entry@sfg@@AAEIH@Z)   C:\Program Files (x86)\CMake 2.8\bin\Entry.cpp.obj  sfgui
Error   12  error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol "__declspec(dllimport) public: class std::_String_iterator<class std::_String_val<struct std::_Simple_types<unsigned int> > > __thiscall sf::String::end(void)" (__imp_?end@String@sf@@QAE?AV?$_String_iterator@V?$_String_val@U?$_Simple_types@I@std@@@std@@@std@@XZ)    C:\Program Files (x86)\CMake 2.8\bin\Label.cpp.obj  sfgui
Error   13  error LNK1120: 4 unresolved externals   C:\Program Files (x86)\CMake 2.8\bin\Debug\sfgui-d.dll  sfgui
```

Do you know how to fix it? I was searching answer on the internet, but it hasn't helped me. It is library, not my project, so I should not change code.

Comment: I just love linker error messages - the essence of clarity and readability.

Answer (score 0):

This class `sf::String` is not provided by **SFGUI** itself, but rather by that underlying cross-platform library **SFML**. Seems like its libraries were not included in the build properly.

Make sure **SFML** is found correctly during the CMake run, check if its .lib binaries were produced in the right place (not just the includes), look if those libraries are specified when running `link.exe` in the output of `nmake VERBOSE=1` etc. Also re-check that **SFML** did build correctly earlier, check for possible install step in it and so on.